# SQLIte Cursor - finalising on null that has not been deactivated or closed Exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

before you ask I have looked around for a solution to my problem and I can't work it out myself, hence coming to you guys.

**THE PROBLEM**

I have an uncaught exception  problem with my cursor and I cannot work it out....

**ERROR**

```
09-04 15:48:38.863: I/dalvikvm(1421): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
09-04 15:48:38.863: I/dalvikvm(1421): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44ef6598 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
09-04 15:48:38.863: I/dalvikvm(1421):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
09-04 15:48:38.873: I/dalvikvm(1421):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**CODE THAT ITS COMPLAINING ABOUT**

```
public CCTrackLocation getTrackLocationForID(int id) {
        CCTrackLocation trackLocation = new CCTrackLocation();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TRACK_LOCATION+" WHERE \"id\" = "+ String.valueOf(id);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                trackLocation.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                trackLocation.segmentID = cursor.getInt(1);
                trackLocation.timestamp = cursor.getDouble(2);
                trackLocation.latitude = cursor.getDouble(3);
                trackLocation.longitude = cursor.getDouble(4);
                trackLocation.altitude = cursor.getDouble(5);
                trackLocation.velocity = cursor.getDouble(6);
                trackLocation.heading = cursor.getDouble(7);
                trackLocation.haccuracy = cursor.getDouble(8);
                trackLocation.vaccuracy = cursor.getDouble(9);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return trackLocation;
    }
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem here is what I did.

1. Only opened and closed the database once. Even if I opened and closed the database every time I used it, sometimes it wasn't quick enough I think and hence I got the errors.
2. Closed the cursor after everytime I used it and had finished with it. This sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe put all of the db code inside a try/catch/finally clause and move the cursor.close() and  db.close() to the finally part of it, to make sure that you are closing the cursor and db even if an exception is thrown before